# Defacto tutorial for C/Unix sockets?

Tags: sockets, unix

Is there a defacto tutorial or book on using sockets (not domain sockets)? More specifically I want to learn more about client <=> server programming.

Comment: How about [Beej's guide to network programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)?

Comment: Are you talking about Unix Domain Sockets or Internet Sockets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H2CO3 mentions Beej's Guide which is a good free introduction.  That's as close to a defacto tutorial as you are likely to find agreement on.

If you want more than an intro tutorial then there  are the [Richard Stevens books](http://www.kohala.com/start/), particular Network `Programming Vol 1` and `Unix Network Programming`.  Some people think they are getting a little outdated but even with the lack of updates they are so much more comprehensive that most anything else out there I don't see it as a real drawback.